# how do i add project references to swcs in FlashDevelop

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flashdevelop

I am trying to add a project reference or swc to papervision in FlashDevelop but intellisense isn't picking it up. I've done it before but i forgot how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add your swc to the lib folder of your project. Then right-click it and mark "Add To Library".

Answer (score 8):

In the menus:

```
Project -> Properties -> Compiler Options -> SWC Libraries
```

(and then add the path or file to the list)